# Do while loop or while loop

Tags: c

I would like to hear some feedback about style on my program, and which one is better "do while" or "while loop" to run my program.
Also, where I suppose to put a condition if the user inputs an invalid option like a letter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Tequila 20
#define Whiskey 25

int main()
{
    int choice = 0;
    int bottle1= 0;
    int bottle2= 0;
    int final_total= 0;
    int total1 =0;
    int total2 =0;

    do{
        printf("\tMain Menu MK liquor Store\n");
        printf(" \tEnter your choice: \n");
        printf("\t 1-  Buy Tequila Jose Cuervo\n");
        printf("\t 2-  Buy Whiskey Jack Daniels\n");
        printf("\t 3-  Quit\n");

        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("how many bottles of Tequila would you like\n");
                scanf("%d", &bottle1);
                printf("so far you got %d bottles in your basket \n", bottle1);

                break;
            case 2:
                printf("how many bottles of Whiskey would you like\n");
                scanf("%d", &bottle2);
                printf("so far you got %d bottles in your basket\n", bottle2);


                break;
            case 3:
                total1=bottle1 * Tequila;
                total2= bottle2 * Whiskey;
                final_total = total1+total2;
                printf("You obtained %d bottles of Tequila and %d of Whisky\n", bottle1,bottle2);
                printf("Your total  is %d dollars\n",final_total);

                break;
            default:

                printf("ERROR INVALID OPTION.\n\n");

                break;

        }

    }while (choice != 3);
        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: you should probably take at look at (and maybe migrate this question to) https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Quick style comment, I would add the units to the names of your #defs, i.e., TEQUILA_PRICE_USD and WHISKEY_PRICE_USD are far more maintainable when someone else has to review and/or modify your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need it to run at least once use a do-while loop. It's *generally* that simple. [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_loops.htm) says

> It is more like a while statement, except that it tests the condition at the end of the loop body.

So use that general rule of thumb.

Comment: I believe the "do while" is allowed inside of a macro, but a "while" may not be

Comment: @grambo what you believe is not correct.

Comment: And whereas the essence of this post is correct, do know Alex that the TutorialsPoint is the absolutely worst "authority" to appeal to.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I know, I usually try to give more beginner-friendly sites when I make reference.